# true and magnetic heading estimation on iOS default reference frame

Tags: ios, core-location, accelerometer, magnetometer, sensor-fusion

I am currently working on heading estimation for iOS and I am recording `trueHeading` and `magneticHeading` using CoreLocation and I am also recording raw magnetometer data along with calibrated magnetometer data.

I have observed that in the default reference frame, `CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical`, I always get 0 for Calibrated Magnetic Data. Am I doing something wrong?

Also, in some papers, I found a formula to calculate heading from magnetometer. The formula is as follows:

H = -atan2(my,mx) where mx, my and H are x component of magnetometer, y component of magnetometer and H is heading.

When I apply the above formula, the estimated heading does not match either the MagneticHeading or the TrueHeading from CoreLocation.

So how do I obtain Heading?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to help you.

> I have observed that in the default reference frame,
>   CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical, I always get 0 for
>   Calibrated Magnetic Data. Am I doing something wrong?
>   Yes. You shouldn't get zero results.

Here is code snippet that demonstrates, how you should get sensor data at iOs:

```
[motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame: CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXMagneticNorthZVertical
                                                            toQueue: sensorsQueue
                                                            withHandler:^ (CMDeviceMotion motionData, NSError error)

   {
     if(error != NULL){
       DLog(@"sensors error info: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
     }
     else
     {
       sensorEntryM.type      = SENSOR_ENTRY_MAGNETOMETER;
       sensorEntryM.values[0] = motionData.magneticField.field.x;
       sensorEntryM.values[1] = motionData.magneticField.field.y;
       sensorEntryM.values[2] = motionData.magneticField.field.z;
       sensorEntryM.values[3] = motionData.magneticField.accuracy;

     }
   }];
```

But be aware that sensor measurements are obtained in the body frame that is strongly connected with device. In order to get heading angle you should transform body frame to global [ENU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axes_conventions#Ground_reference_frames:_ENU_and_NED) frame. 
It worth to note that your formula

> H = -atan2(my,mx)

is correct only for measurements at ENU frame.
To find such a transformation or rotation matrix you should know pitch and roll angles of the device.
Please refer to this answer for more details.

You can also explore good [Sensor Fusion manual](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/729759/Android-Sensor-Fusion-Tutorial) with detailed description.

Comment: Thank you Alex. So when I change the reference frame to `CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXMagneticNorthZVertical` I do get calibrated data but not when I use `CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical`. I agree that I need to convert the data to world frame. The way I am doing it is: record Quaternions, obtain Rotation matrix from Quaternions and use this Rotation matrix to convert the data to world frame. Then apply the equation for heading, but still I do not get any close to iOS heading. Also the device is resting on a table facing up so pitch and roll should be around zero.